# Javascript about looping checkbox

Tags: javascript

Just want to ask, why the following code is not valid (error found)

```
for(var i=1; i<10; i++)
{
  alert(window.document.FORM.checkbox[i].checked);

}
```

but i can do the following, i just want to loop the checkbox that created in html:

```
for(var i=1; i<10; i++)
{
  alert(window.document.FORM.checkbox1.checked);

}
```

Comment: Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference

Comment: `alert(window.document.FORM["checkbox" + i ].checked);`

Comment: where is your html code ?

Comment: `FORM` has distinctive elements as its children. In order to obtain a `Node list` you need to perform some operation, such as `getElementsByTagName()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two statements are not the same; when i equals 1 your statement will be evaluated as

```
alert(window.document.FORM.checkbox[1].checked);
```

which is not the same as

```
alert(window.document.FORM.checkbox1.checked);
```

so indeed, to do this, use Lee Taylor's solution, or maybe rewrite the entire method using id's or getting all the checkboxes via document.getElementsByTagName, eg

```
var chks = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0, l=chks.length; i<l; i++) { 
  if ( chks[i].type === "checkbox" ) 
    alert(chks[i].checked);
}
```

HTH, 
bovako

Answer (score 0):

So strange but your code works for me.

```js
for(var i=1; i<10; i++)
{
  alert(window.document.FORM.checkbox[i].checked);

}
```

```html
<form name="FORM">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="true" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="true" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="true" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="true" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
</form>
```